# Getting errors in Struts2 application

Tags: struts2, tomcat7

These are the jar files I'm using:

```
commons-fileupload-1.2.2.jar
commons-io-2.0.1.jar
commons-lang3-3.1.jar
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
commons-logging-api-1.1.jar
freemarker-2.3.19.jar
javassist-3.11.0.GA.jar
ognl-3.0.6.jar
struts2-core-2.3.8.jar
struts2-dojo-plugin-2.3.8.jar
xwork-core-2.3.8.jar
```

**struts.xml** - present in the web content folder of the project

```
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
 "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
  "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
 <struts>
    <package name="Login" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="login" class="org.jolly.struts.action.LoginAction">
                <result name="SUCCESS">register.jsp</result>
                <result name="LOGIN">login.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>

    <package name="Register" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="register" class="org.jolly.struts.action.FormAction">
                <result name="SUCCESS">success.jsp</result>

        </action>
    </package>
```

**web.xml** - present in web content folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"         
 xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"  
 xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
 http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>RegisterForm</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>login.jsp</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<filter>
<filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
<filter-class>
            org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher
</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

**Action classes**

**LoginAction.java**

```
package org.jolly.action;

 import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

 import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

 public class LoginAction extends ActionSupport{

private String userId;
private String password;

public String execute(){
    if(getUserId().equals("user") && getPassword().equals("password"))
        return SUCCESS;
    else
        return LOGIN ;

}

public String getUserId() {
    return userId;
}

public void setUserId(String userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public void validate(){

    if(StringUtils.isEmpty(getUserId())) {
        addFieldError("userId","UserId cannot be blank");
    }

    if(StringUtils.isEmpty(getPassword())) {
        addFieldError("password","Password cannot be blank");
    }
}

}
```

**FormAction.java**

```java
package org.jolly.action;

  import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
  import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

  public class FormAction extends ActionSupport{

private String name;
private String emailId;

public String execute(){
    return SUCCESS;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getEmailId() {
    return emailId;
}

public void setEmailId(String emailId) {
    this.emailId = emailId;
}

   public void validate(){
    if(StringUtils.isEmpty(getName())) {
        addFieldError("name","Name cannot be blank");
    }

    if(StringUtils.isEmpty(getEmailId())) {
        addFieldError("emailid","Email Id cannot be blank");
    }
}
```

**JSP's**

**1. Login.jsp**

```
  <%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%> 

<html>
<body>
<s:form action="login">
      <s:textfield label="User Id" key="userid"/>
      <s:password label="Password" key="password"/>
</s:form>
</body>
</html>
```

**2.Register.jsp**

```
    <%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
    <%@ taglib prefix="sx" uri="/struts-dojo-tags"%>

     <html>
     <head>
      <s:head/>
      <sx:head/>
     </head>
     <body>
     <s:form action="register">
     <s:textfield label="Enter Your Name" key="name"/>
     <s:textfield label="Enter Your Email Id" key="emailId"/>
     <s:checkbox name= "Gender" fieldvalue="Female" value="true"/>
     <s:checkbox name ="Gender" fieldvalue="Male"/>
     <s:checkbox name ="Gender" fieldvalue="Others"/>
     <sx:autocompleter label= "Country" list ="{'India','Pakistan','U.S'}"/>
     <s:textarea key="add" name="address"/>
     <sx:datetimepicker name="date" label="Date" displayFormat="dd/MM/yyyy"/>
    <s:submit value= "Submit Form"/>
 </s:form>
  </body>
```

**3.Success.jsp**

```
  <html>
  <body>
   Form is submitted successfully!!
 </body>
  </html>
```

**ERRORS**

```
SEVERE: Dispatcher initialization failed
 Unable to load configuration. - action - 

 file:/C:/Users/JOLLY/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp2/wtpweba 
 pps/RegisterForm%20(1)/WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml:7:69
    at  
 com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager. 
 java:70)
    at 
 org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:429)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:471)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.init(FilterDispatcher.java:193)
    at 
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:2
 81)
    at 
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:26
 2)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>
 (ApplicationFilterConfig.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4656)
    at 
 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5312)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: Action class [org.jolly.struts.action.LoginAction] not found - action -  
 file:/C:/Users/JOLLY/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp2/wtpweba
 pps/RegisterForm%20(1)/WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml:7:69
    at 
 com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.verifyAction(XmlConfigur
 ationProvider.java:480)
    at 
 com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.addAction(XmlConfigurati
 onProvider.java:424)
    at 
 com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.addPackage(XmlConfigurat
 ionProvider.java:541)
    at c

 com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadPackages(XmlConfigur
 ationProvider.java:290)
    at 
 org.apache.struts2.config.StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.loadPackages(StrutsXmlConfigurati
 onProvider.java:112)
    at 
 com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfigurat
 ion.java:239)
    at 
 com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.
 java:67)
    ... 16 more
    Feb 27, 2013 12:12:12 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart

 SEVERE: Exception starting filter struts2

 Unable to load configuration. - action - 
 file:/C:/Users/JOLLY/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp2/wtpweba
 pps/RegisterForm%20(1)/WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml:7:69
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:483)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.init(FilterDispatcher.java:193)
    at 
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:2 81)
    at 
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:26 
 2)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init> 
 (ApplicationFilterConfig.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4656)
    at 

 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5312)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: Unable to load configuration. - action - 
 file:/C:/Users/JOLLY/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp2/wtpweba
 pps/RegisterForm%20(1)/WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml:7:69
    at 
 com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.
 java:70)
    at 
 org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:429)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:471)
    ... 14 more

 Caused by: Action class [org.jolly.struts.action.LoginAction] not found - action - 
 file:/C:/Users/JOLLY/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp2/wtpweba
 pps/RegisterForm%20(1)/WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml:7:69
    at 
 com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.verifyAction(XmlConfigur
 ationProvider.java:480)
    at 
 com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.addAction(XmlConfigurati
 onProvider.java:424)
    at 
 com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.addPackage(XmlConfigurat
 ionProvider.java:541)
    at 
 com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadPackages(XmlConfigur
 ationProvider.java:290)
    at 
 org.apache.struts2.config.StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.loadPackages(StrutsXmlConfigurati
 onProvider.java:112)
    at 
 com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfigurat
 ion.java:239)
    at 
 com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.
 java:67)
    ... 16 more

     Feb 27, 2013 12:12:12 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
     SEVERE: Error filterStart
     Feb 27, 2013 12:12:12 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
     SEVERE: Context [/RegisterForm_(1)] startup failed due to previous errors
     Feb 27, 2013 12:12:12 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
     INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
     Feb 27, 2013 12:12:12 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
     INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
     Feb 27, 2013 12:12:13 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
     INFO: Server startup in 9975 ms
```

Please anyone could help. I've been trying this since two weeks.

Comment: place filter first in web.xml

Comment: The application is missconfigured, incomplete, don't even possible to know what it was asked here.

Answer (score 0):

The error message says exactly what's wrong.

Your configuration file uses one package for your action class, your action class is in another.

Your next problem will be that your results won't be found because the config file uses all upper-case result names, while the constant values are all lower-case.

You're also using the old filter. And why is the validation logic duplicated?

Answer (score 0):

The struts.xml file should be placed in

Either

1) In Java Resources--> src folder-->struts.xml.

OR

2) In WebContent-->WEB-INF-->classes (make a new folder with name "classes")--> struts.xml